# jQuery doesn't find appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to hack fullcalendar in order to display multiple events per row in my calendar. So in order to do that I want to iterate through this rows and reorganise their content. However, jQuery can't `find()` these rows.

```
<div class="fc-content-skeleton">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="fc-day-number fc-mon fc-past" data-date="2016-09-26">26</td>
                <td class="fc-day-number fc-tue fc-past" data-date="2016-09-27">27</td>
                <td class="fc-day-number fc-wed fc-past" data-date="2016-09-28">28</td>
                <td class="fc-day-number fc-thu fc-past" data-date="2016-09-29">29</td>
                <td class="fc-day-number fc-fri fc-today fc-state-highlight" data-date="2016-09-30">30</td>
                <td class="fc-day-number fc-sat fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2016-10-01">1</td>
                <td class="fc-day-number fc-sun fc-other-month fc-future" data-date="2016-10-02">2</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2"></td>
                <td class="fc-event-container" rowspan="2">
                    <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end event-free" data-url=""></a>
                </td>
                <td rowspan="2"></td>
                <td class="fc-event-container">
                    <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end event-mine" data-url=""></a>
                </td>
                <td class="fc-event-container">
                    <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end event-free" data-url=""></a>
                </td>
                <td rowspan="2"></td>
                <td rowspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="fc-event-container">
                    <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end event-taken" data-url=""></a>
                </td>
                <td class="fc-event-container">
                    <a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end event-free" data-url=""></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I am able to get to `table` tag under `.fc-content-skeleton`. But when I call 'find("table").children()' it returns only `thead` but not `tbody` that I need. I am doing that after all events were fetched and appended.

**EDIT**

The function is called as follows:

```
    $(document).on("ready turbolinks:load", function(){
       //.....

       $("#calendar").fullCalendar(calendarOpt);
       $("#calendar").reorganizeEvents();

       //.....
}):
```

The function itself:

```
(function($) {
   $.fn.reorganizeEvents = function(){
    if(reorgHandler == false){
      $(this).fullCalendar('render');
      var $dayContainers = $(this).find(".fc-row .fc-content-skeleton table")
           .children(); //obtaining children of the table in .fc-skeleton.
             // Supposed to be <thead> and <tbody>
          console.log($dayContainers); //successfully finds table
          $dayContainers.each(function(index){ 
            console.log($(this)); //shows only <thead> as a single child
          });
          reorgHandler = true;
        }
      }
    }(jQuery));
```

Comment: And where are you calling this JavaScript code? My crystal ball is saying you are trying to access the elements before they exist.

Comment: @epascarello That, or it could be working with a variable value from before they existed as well. Depends on when the `find()...` is written.

Comment: @epascarello I am calling it on the `$("#calendar")` after the fullcalendar is instantiated in the `document.ready` function.

Comment: My guess is it has not rendered at that point, you probably need to either call render than look for your elements.

Comment: @epascarello Called `fullCalendar('render')` before calling the function. Didn't work. Update the post to show how I call it.

Answer (score 2):

Put your JavaScript at the bottom of the page, before the closing of the `</body>`

or use

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
  $(".fc-content-skeleton").find("table").children();
})
```

Comment: I am calling the function from the `document.ready` block. I have updated my question to show how I it's done.

Answer (score 0):

As @epascarello pointed out, the elements were not rendered at the moment when I was trying to access them. Calling render function explicitly didn't fix the problem. However, fullcalendar has an `eventAfterAllRender` callback that fires after all events are rendered. Calling my function on this callback fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the [eventAfterRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterRender/)

you can wait that the element is rendered and then select it.